# Drupal 5 CCK field not loaded into node

Tags: drupal, cck, drupal-5

[Drupal 5.22, CCK 5.x-1.10]

I have a Sermon content type that accepts a CCK text field labeled Minister. After creating a new Sermon, the Minister field label is shown, but not the value. I've verified that the value is being stored in the database. I am logged in as user1 with all permissions, but the field still does not display.

However, if I re-submit the node, the Minister field appears. Anybody know why it's not being displayed the first time?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried if emptying the cache solves the problem? (In Drupal 6 you can do it on a button on the bottom of the page at your-domain/admin/settings/performance, I think it is  the same place in Drupal 5).